# How do you create a button that clears all array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, input

I'm new to javascript and I was trying to create a code to clear all data in an array via a button. How it works is that once i click a certain map area, it would put that data inside the textarea. And the output would be an array. But when i try deleting it and clicking on another map area, the previous data would appear.
I just want to know how to clear the data without it appearing The sample codes are below. Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/qpmxnv2g/5/

HTML

```
<img src="http://79.170.44.80/sicuandomain.com/img/Capture.JPG" alt="" usemap="#Map" />
<map name="Map" id="Map">

<area class="red" alt="" title="Right Hand"  href="#" shape="poly" coords="19,317,45,317,50,334,58,365,55,367,46,367,44,379,35,385,22,378,17,345,4,353,3,341" />

<area class="red" alt="" title="Right Forearm"  href="#" shape="poly" coords="32,224,18,316,47,317,68,224" />

<area class="red" alt="" title="Right Bicep"  href="#" shape="poly" coords="45,119,37,137,35,223,67,228,61,159,45,119" />

<area class="red" alt="" title="Pelvis"  href="#" shape="poly" coords="96,297,136,297,128,318,111,320" />

<area class="red" alt="" title="Left Forearm"  href="#" shape="poly" coords="167,216,198,216,212,314,187,315,177,273,169,250" />

<area class="red"alt="" title="Left Bicep"  href="#" shape="poly" coords="178,109,164,159,168,213,195,213,197,176,191,124,189,115" />

<area id="red"alt="" title="Right Foot"  href="#" shape="poly" coords="86,557,110,559,112,622,96,632,75,627" />
<area class="red"alt="" title="Left Foot"  href="#" shape="poly" coords="144,557,145,591,153,619,129,634,114,623,120,557" />
<area class="red"alt="" title="Left Leg"  href="#" shape="poly" coords="155,453,157,495,145,558,119,558,118,453" />
<area class="red"alt="" title="Neck"  href="#" shape="poly" coords="92,72,107,88,124,88,137,72,137,90,143,95,119,107,90,95,96,88," />
<area class="red" alt="" title="Face"  href="#" shape="poly" coords="90,16,114,5,136,16,145,58,135,74,115,87,96,72,84,60" />
<area class="red"alt="" title="Chest"  href="#" shape="poly" coords="45,119,90,97,118,111,145,97,175,110,165,175,62,175" />
<area class="red"alt="" title="Stomach"  href="#" shape="poly" coords="62,180,170,173,165,218,162,243,165,265,142,293,95,294,65, 270,70,245,64,219" />
<area class="red"alt="" title="Left Hand"  href="#" shape="poly" coords="188,318,208,316,217,324,230,347,222,350,212,342,209,376,193, 380,183,375,183,355,174,364,180,338,184,318" />
<area class="red"alt="" title="Right Thigh"  href="#" shape="poly" coords="67,274,119,340,116,452,79,452,78,433,61,363" />
<area class="red"alt="" title="Left Thigh"  href="#" shape="poly" coords="119,340,167,266,176,314,172,359,157,452,154,453,117,453" />
<area class="red"alt="" title="Left Leg"  href="#" shape="poly" coords="78,453,77,512,87,557,109,558,115,454" />
<area class="red"alt="" title="Back Head"  href="#" shape="poly" coords="369,4,351,17,350,44,360,66,396,66,404,45,407,21,387,4" />
<area class="red" alt="" title="Back Neck"  href="#" shape="poly" coords="361,66,354,93,377,97,401,92,396,68" />
<area class="red" alt="" title="Right Tricep" href="#" shape="poly" coords="444,116,453,219,425,227,420,205,430,139" />
<area class="red"alt="" title="Back Body"  href="#" shape="poly" coords="353,92,307,115,325,173,323,249,374,258,420,249,424,171,442,114,403,92,376,100" />
<area class="red"alt="" title="Left Tricep"  href="#" shape="poly" coords="305,116,298,142,294,219,321,225,323,170" />
<area class="red"alt="" title="Left Backarm"  href="#" shape="poly" coords="293,219,285,239,280,303,301,309,319,246,319,228" />
<area class="red"alt="" title="Right Backarm"  href="#" shape="poly" coords="426,228,455,222,462,249,464,308,446,310,437,281" />
<area class="red"alt="" title="Buttocks"  href="#" shape="poly" coords="322,250,313,305,335,326,361,332,372,325,385,330,404,329,430,315,429,289,421,253,374,258" />
<area class="red" alt="" title="Back Left-Hand" href="#" shape="poly" coords="277,308,260,335,280,372,289,373,303,365,307,332,302,310" />
<area class="red" alt="" title="Back Right-Hand" href="#" shape="poly" coords="443,312,466,309,485,330,476,358,460,370,442,359" />
<area class="red" alt="" title="Left Hamstring" href="#" shape="poly" coords="312,306,344,331,363,331,373,327,370,436,331,435,319,376" />
<area class="red" alt="" title="Right Hamstring" href="#" shape="poly" coords="375,325,399,330,430,314,428,368,415,407,414,436,376,435,377,400,374,372" />
<area class="red" alt="" title="Left Calves" href="#" shape="poly" coords="333,436,366,440,365,453,371,486,366,515,,365,542,342,543,344,535,334,492" />
<area class="red" alt="" title="Right Calves" href="#" shape="poly" coords="377,436,414,437,410,452,413,487,400,543,378,543,376,516,374,487,377,456" />
<area class="red" alt="" title="Left Underfoot" href="#" shape="poly" coords="340,545,341,586,335,613,360,633,371,630,366,570,368,545" />
<area class="red" alt="" title="Right Underfoot" href="#" shape="poly" coords="377,546,390,540,401,543,405,553,403,587,410,614,390,633,374,631,372,610,378,565" />

</map>
<p>You have clicked: </p><textarea name="body" id="body"></textarea>
<input id="Clear" type="submit" name="clear"value="Clear "></input>
<input id="submit1"type="submit" name="submit"value="Submit"></input>
```

Javascript

```
var map = document.getElementById("Map");
    map.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    callAction(e.target);
    });
var body = [];
document.getElementbyId("body").innerHTML = body;


function callAction(area) {
    body.push(area.title);
    document.getElementById("body").value = body;
}

var clear = document.getElementById("Clear");

function clear(){
    body.length=0;
    document.getElementById("Clear").value = body;
}
```

Comment: Reedited it. Link to JSBin

Answer (score 0):

Please provide your array and is it on purpose that the value of textarea will have a copy written on the button?

or if you want to clear the textarea,

```js
document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting your array to empty like so:

```
arrayName = []
```

Or by using a while loop to pop all of your elements out of the array:

```
while(arrayName.length) {
    arrayName.pop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code:

> TypeError: `document.getElementbyId` is not a function

Maybe you meant `document.getElementById`.

---

The <kbd>Clear</kbd> button has no event listener.

Also, you’re overwriting the value of *the clear button* upon clearing, instead the value of the textarea.

Instead of `var clear = …` and `function clear`, *which use the same name*, write

```
document.getElementById("Clear").addEventListener('click',function(){
  body.length=0;
  document.getElementById("body").value='';
});
```

---

`type="submit"` makes no sense outside a `<form>` and should be a `type="button"` (for the <kbd>Clear</kbd> button).

---

All in all, [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qpmxnv2g/6/) is the improved version.

Answer (score -1):

Do you need to clear text-area value or anything else?
Your question is litle bit confusing.

If you want to clear your textarea then you can use below code:

```
document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = "";
```